# How to classify user input testset in Naive Bayes Classifier in python?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

I am trying to get a result for user-provided input. The following is a generic code that I came across which works something like this:
The input dataset is split into a training set and testing set. The training set is used to train the Naive Bayes model and the testing set is used to test the trained model for the result. As a result, it predicts the accuracy of how may test sets have been predicted correctly.

```
import csv
import math
import random

""" 
Load the CSV File
"""

def loadCSV(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(open(r'diabetes.csv'))
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset

"""
Training
"""

def splitDataset(dataset, splitRatio):
    trainSize = int(len(dataset) * splitRatio)
    trainSet = []
    copy = list(dataset)
    while len(trainSet) < trainSize:
        index = random.randrange(len(copy))
        trainSet.append(copy.pop(index))
    return [trainSet, copy]

def seperateByClass(dataset):
    separated = {}
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        vector = dataset[i]
        if (vector[-1] not in separated):
            separated[vector[-1]] = []
        separated[vector[-1]].append(vector)
    return separated

def mean(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)/float(len(numbers))

def stdev(numbers):
    avg = mean(numbers)
    variance = sum([pow(x-avg, 2) for x in numbers])/float(len(numbers)-1)
    return math.sqrt(variance)

def summarize(dataset):
    summaries = [(mean(attribute), stdev(attribute)) for attribute in zip(*dataset)]
    del summaries[-1]
    return summaries

def summariesByClass(dataset):
    separated = seperateByClass(dataset)
    summaries = {}
    for classValue, instances in separated.items():
        summaries[classValue] = summarize(instances)
    return summaries

"""
Prediction
"""

def calculateProbability(x, mean, stdev):
    exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x-mean, 2)/(2*math.pow(stdev, 2))))
    return (1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*stdev))*exponent

def calculateClassProbabilities(summaries, inputVector):
    probabilities = {}
    for classValue, classSummaries in summaries.items():
        probabilities[classValue] = 1
        for i in range(len(classSummaries)):
            mean, stdev = classSummaries[i]
            x = inputVector[i]
            probabilities[classValue] *= calculateProbability(x, mean, stdev)
        return probabilities

def predict(summaries, inputVector):
    probabilities = calculateClassProbabilities(summaries, inputVector)
    bestLabel, bestProb = None, -1
    for classValue, probability in probabilities.items():
        if bestLabel is None or probability > bestProb:
            bestProb = probability
            bestLabel = classValue
    return bestLabel

def getPredictions(summaries, testSet):
    predictions = []
    for i in range(len(testSet)):
        result = predict(summaries, testSet[i])
        predictions.append(result)
    return predictions

def getAccuracy(testSet, Predictions):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        if testSet[x][-1] == Predictions[x]:
            correct += 1
    return (correct/float(len(testSet)))*100.0

"""
Main Method
"""

def main():
    filename = 'diabetes.csv'
    splitRatio = 0.66
    dataset = loadCSV(filename)
    trainSet, testSet = splitDataset(dataset, splitRatio)
    print('Split {0} rows into train = {1} and test = {2} rows'.format(len(dataset),len(trainSet), len(testSet)))

    summaries = summariesByClass(trainSet)

    # Test Model
    predictions = getPredictions(summaries, testSet)
    print(predictions)

    accuracy = getAccuracy(testSet, predictions)

    print('Accuracy : {0}%'.format(accuracy))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The modification that I want to make is instead of splitting the dataset into training and testing dataset, use the dataset entirely to train the model and give a user input and check whether we get results.
i.e. In our [dataset](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AraAt5PIeeL0hLdqRx5Bit-r8fHaaw) we are predicting whether a patient would be a victim of diabetes or not based on the dataset provided to the model. So I want to give a user input something like this:

```
testSet = [[6, 148, 72, 36, 0, 33.6, 0.627, 50], [8, 183, 64, 0, 0, 23.3, 0.672, 32]]
```

Note: These are the random two rows of our dataset just to test the output.

Expected output for this given test set is :

```
result = 0.0 # For 1st sample 
result = 1.0 # For 2nd sample
```

Please Do help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To train the model using all the data as training set just set the

```
splitRatio=1
```

indeed the training set size is computed using the expression:

```
trainSize = int(len(dataset) * splitRatio)
```

In order to accept input from the user and transfrom it into a list, you can use:

```
# user input 6 148 72 36 0 33.6 0.627 50
testSet=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Comment: here the inputs are in both int and float so `testSet=[int(x) for x in input().split()]` this is failing.. :(

Comment: @BlackPanther my bad. simply change the code from testSet=[int(x) for x in input().split()] to testSet=[float(x) for x in input().split()].